# Limit file access to admin and application on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, access-control, windows-10, file-access

I'm looking for a way to secure special made config files on an Windows 10 installation:

- A user without admin rights must not have direct access to the unencrypted text file.
- A closed source application which the user needs must have unrestricted access to it's config file.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are 'unencrypted text file' and 'config file' one and the same?

Comment: yes they are the same

Comment: So you are asking, essentially: "How can I make a file unreadable to a user that needs to read it?" The answer is basically that you can't.

Comment: Not really, the application needs higher permissions than the executing user. Is that possible?

Comment: If the user runs the application, then the user must be able to read the configuration file. This is because the application runs as that user.

Answer (score 2):

There's no really easy way, I'm afraid. The assumption in most of computer security, dating clear back to the first multi-user systems, is that anything a program running under a user can see, then another program running under that user (such as Notepad) can also see. This has been changed somewhat by the introduction of app sandboxing, but all that does is let you make it so some specific program(s) can see *less* than other programs; it doesn't give them the ability to see *more*.

To do this, you'll need to create a new account (or use the Administrator account, but that's needlessly dangerous) for the program to run in, and then create a way for a non-admin user to launch that program *as that user* without being able to launch any *other* program as that user. On Unix-like operating systems that's relatively easy - the "setuid" bit in file permissions would let you do this - but it's harder on Windows.

Here's one way, if you don't mind doing a little work for each non-admin user and are using Win10 Pro or Enterprise (or other recent "Professional-or-higher" Windows edition):

1. Create the "SecureApp" user.
2. Set the app's config file to be full access for the new SecureApp user, but no access for anybody else (at least, any other non-admin).
3. Create a shortcut that uses the `runas.exe` program with the `/savecred` parameter. The full command will look something like this: `runas.exe /savecred /user:SecureApp C:\path\to\the\application.exe`. See [this forum post](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/164915-run-different-user-shortcut-create-specified-program-user.html) for a step-by-step.
4. Run the shortcut once for the non-admin user, and enter the password of the SecureApp user when prompted.

The user can then run that shortcut to launch the program. Launching the program directly won't work, and you may need to do step 4 once for *each* non-admin user who needs access (even if they all log into the same computer and you put the shortcut on the all-users desktop or similar). Also note that the program won't have access to the user's own files or settings (more accurately, won't have access to the user's profile directory or current-user registry); if the program needs such access you will have to manually give the SecureApp user access to those items. **Also, you need to make sure that your users never find out the password for the SecureApp user, or they can invoke `runas` themselves with some other program (like `notepad`) to go edit the config file.**

Comment: Won't the user be able to start all applications using savecred and therefore accessing the file?